# Edit button hiding to using condition in field Odoo

Tags: odoo

I have 2 groups, one is "expert doctor" the other one is "pratisyen doctor". When expert doctor create a new patient, pratisyen doctor should not be allowed to edit. I tried a lot but I couldn't reach the result. How can i do it?

This is my xml file. attrs:invisible is not working. i need to disable it not invisible.
I inherited from view_patient_form.

```html
<record id="view_patient_form_noedit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hospital.patient.form.noedit</field>
        <field name="model">hospital.patient</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="view_patient_form"/>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('om_hospital.hospital_management_pratisyen_doctor')])]"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr='//form' position='attributes'>
                <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: You can do it with record rule. `ir.rule`